# Access specific value from HTTP-Request

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, url

I send a test HTTP-request to a SharePoint list to get the values of a list item. In return I got (shortened):

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Origin,Accept-Encoding",
        "X-SharePointHealthScore": "1",
        
    },
    "body": {
        "d": {
            
            "PraxisFoto": "{\"type\":\"thumbnail\",\"fileName\":\"Campus_Luftbild.jpg\",\"nativeFile\":{},\"fieldName\":\"PraxisFoto\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://sharepoint123.sharepoint.com\",\"fieldId\":\"c5c89367-f483-4433-a124-e307b51859ef\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/[SiteName]/SiteAssets/Lists/[ListID]/Campus_Luftbild.jpg\",\"id\":\"26eccafb-c4ea-4a6f-8675-xxxxxxx\"}",
            
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to retrieve the value from **serverRelativeUrl** (`/sites/[SiteName]/SiteAssets/Lists/[ListID]/Campus_Luftbild.jpg`) located in the column `PraxisFoto` to get the filename for the image in an image column.

I fail to construct a HTTP-request or a compose action to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `PraxisFoto` property is a string. So you need to convert that string into an object to easily access the value of the `serverRelativeUrl` property. You can do this using the **Initialize variable** action to create an object variable and initializing it's value to the expression: `json(variables('FullObject')['body']['d']['PraxisFoto'])`

Note: I stored the value of the JSON object you posted in your question in a variable named `FullObject`. You need to replace the reference to that variable in the expression in your flow.

[image: Initialize variable]

Then you can use this expression to get the value of the serverRelativeUrl property in a **Compose** action: `variables('BodyObject')['serverRelativeUrl']`

Comment: Works very well, thank you. I just needed to remove the [body] part from the json() expression to get it work.